# How to build Helloword in android custom kernel

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, kernel, android-kernel

`insmod: failed to load hello.ko: Function not implemented`
during kernel build to logout message like 'hello world', I've got such an error, following steps will reproduce the bug:

1)I downloaded goldfish kernel from `git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/goldfish/ -b android-goldfish-3.18`

2)also downloaded the toolchain coming with the above repo using `git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/x86/x86_64-linux-android-4.9`

3)I changed directory to goldfish and created the paths mentioned in the documentation ([github](https://gist.github.com/yan12125/78a9004acb1bed5faf2ffd442163e2ef))

4)then i attempted to build the kernel using this `sudo make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE=/home/ana/x86_64-linux-android-4.9-nougat-dev/bin/x86_64-linux-android-` in the kernel directory (goldfish) and set LOADABLE_MODULES=y

5)In the next step, I created hello.c file and the Makefile related to it in helloKernel directory.

hello.c

```
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/init.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>

MODULE_AUTHOR("Robert P. J. Day");
MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");
MODULE_VERSION("2:1.0") ;
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("You have to start somewhere.");


static int hello_init(void){
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello TheLittleNaruto it’s your first driver.\n");
return 0;
}

static void hello_exit(void){
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye TheLittleNaruto No point in keeping this driv er running.\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

Makefile

```
obj-m := hello.o  

KERNELDIR := /home/ana/goldfish/
PWD :=$(shell pwd)  
ARCH=x86_64 
CROSS_COMPILE=/home/ana/x86_64-linux-android-4.9-nougat-dev/bin/x86_64-linux-android-
CC=$(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc  
LD=$(CROSS_COMPILE)ld  
CFLAGS_MODULE=-fno-pic  

modules:  
    make -C $(KERNELDIR) ARCH=$(ARCH) CROSS_COMPILE=$(CROSS_COMPILE) M=$(PWD) modules    
clean:    
    rm *.o *.ko *.mod.c *.order *.symvers
```

6. in the same directory I created hello.ko with this `sudo make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE=/home/ana/x86_64-linux-android-4.9-nougat-dev/bin/x86_64-linux-android-`

7)and then i copied hello.ko to android emulator using `sudo adb push hello.ko /data/local`

8)and then i attempt `insmod hello.ko` in `/data/local`

and I get the above-mentioned error, please help me solve this problem. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

two things to add in your code

- function entry and exit routine
  module_init(init_module);
  module_exit(cleanup_module);
- Let init_module function return 0 rather 1 because 0 means we are good.

Comment: I add above functions but i get same error

Comment: can you please show us the complete code again

Comment: Do you think the problem with wrong execution of the kernel in the emulator or my hello.c?

Comment: Never seen such error earlier but can you check in your kernel .config if it has enabled CONFIG_MODULES=y and CONFIG_MODULE_UNLOAD=y options

Comment: Yes, enable but i think my kernel have a problem because after i run emulator with custom kernel i see dark image on my emulator

Comment: Kind of running out of idea. lets enable debug_initcall, as somewhere init code is returning ENOSYS, causing this issue. https://chengyihe.wordpress.com/2015/12/13/android-kernel-enable-initcall_debug-to-debug-initcall/

Comment: Can i add and build hello.c in my emulator without building custom kernel? (with defult emulator kernel)